# Add Jar and Classifier as dependency to Maven project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a local Jar file that I want to add as a dependency for a Maven project that I am working on.

That is easy to do as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955695/3961436) answer states.

The problem is that this Jar file requires a `foo.classifier` file to work properly.

This Jar file is meant to be run by command line (`java -jar bar.jar {argument}`). The Jar and the classifier files are in the same directory, so everything works just fine.

However, from my project, I want to call the Jar file using its methods and not running a process.

I added the Jar file as a dependency and managed to call the main method that receives the argument, however, it doesn't work properly because of the `foo.classifier` the file is not set as a dependency for that Jar file to work.

Does anyone know how can I set it as a dependency of that Jar file?

Comment: How are you using foo.classifier files in jar. Reading from classpath or physical path?

Comment: Can you edit the sources and build the `bar.jar` file yourself?

Comment: I was not the one who coded the Jar file, so I don't know how it is used. I only know that both the jar and classifier files must be in the same directory.
Also, I can not edit the sources.

Comment: Do you have the sources and can read the sources of the main method?

Answer (score 0):

Put `foo.classifier` files in exact folder in .m2\repository folder where your local Jar file that you added as a dependency is present as dependency jar will be referred from local repository

Comment: This sounds brittle to me.

Comment: This is like having jar and files together in the same directory

Comment: But local repositories are often deleted, recreated etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your jar to libs directory,and add below code into your **pom.xml** file:

---

``` <dependency>
    <groupId>htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.21-OSGi</version>``
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>the full path of the jar</systemPath>
</dependency> ```

Comment: scope system should be avoided if possible.

Comment: I can't emphasized this strong enough what JF Meier said.

Comment: Yeah,JF Meier is right and I am just talking about a way to use local jar files with Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar to maven repository with the follows command line, specify a group id, artifact id and a version

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="my-local.jar" -DgroupId="my.groupid" -DartifactId="name" -Dversion="1.0.0" -Dpackaging=jar
```

and then add as dependency to your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>name</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```